# Python extraer n valores de listas

Tags: python, pandas

No consigo extraer los valores de un campo tipo lista de un dataframe pandas. El número que aparece en la columna n marca el total de valores de la lista que debe devolver. Os pongo un ejemplo:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'values': [['abc','cd2','axy'],['zxc','csa','vsa'],['was','sdf','kjd']], 'n': ['2','1','3'], 'expected': [['abc', 'cd2'],['zxc'],['was','sdf','kjd']]})
print(df_2)
```

Alguien sabría orientarme como extraer los valores? No domino mucho lambda, y las otras variantes me devuelve error de tipo al indicar la posición con el campo df_2['n']

Gracias

Comment: No entiendo del todo tu pregunta, así que quiero confirmar. Lo que buscas es tomar los primeros n elementos de cada lista y guardar ese resultado en la columna excepted?

Comment: Exactamente, de la primera lista ['abc','cd2','axy'], si la columna n = 2, entonces el resultado en la nueva debería ser ['abc','cd2'], des del principio hasta el número de elementos que indica n.

Comment: `df_2.apply(lambda x: x["values"][:int(x.n)], axis=1)`

Comment: @abulafia el OP no sabe como funciona un lambda, estaría bueno que dieras una respuesta en lugar de publicar el código por que es obvia la respuesta. Todos tenemos un nivel diferente de conocimiento. Además, para mi no fue tan obvio.

Comment: @DanteS. Hecho. Gracias por señalarlo

Comment: De nada Abulafia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método `df.apply()` con la opción `axis=1`.

Lo que hace este método (cuando axis=1) es iterar por cada fila del dataframe y para cada una de las filas invocar una función que tú tienes que escribir y pasarle como parámetro a `apply()` (si no pones axis=1 iteraría en cambio por las columnas).

La función que escribas recibirá un parámetro que es un dataframe de una sola fila (la fila que se esté procesando en ese momento, cuando axis=1).

Supongamos que llamas a ese parámetro `x`. Entonces podrás hacer `x["values"]`  para acceder a la celda que tiene la lista que te interesa procesar, y también `x["n"]` para acceder a la celda con el número de ítems a extraer. En el caso de esta celda también es válido escribir `x.n` que es más corto (en cambio `x.values` no sirve para acceder a la primera porque el nombre `values` entra en conflicto con un atributo que tiene pandas que se llama igual).

Entonces dentro de esa función puedes poner `x["values"][:int(x.n)]` para extraer la sublista que deseas. Efectivamente `x["values"]` te dará la lista completa, y al aplicarle el operador *slice* `[:N]` se extraen los `N` primeros elementos. En este caso usamos como `N` la expresión `int(x.n)` para extraer el número de la celda llamada "n" (y lo convertimos a entero porque en el ejemplo que has planteado era una cadena).

Solo queda escribir esa función que puede ser por tanto así:

```
def extraer_sublista(x):
   return x["values"][:int(x.n)]
```

Y aplicarla en la forma siguiente:

```
df_2.apply(extraer_sublista, axis=1)
```

Ya que `apply()` itera por todas las filas, va recogiendo los sucesivos valores retornados para crear con ellos una "Pandas Series", o sea algo que puede ser asignado a una columna si quieres. Por lo que puedes hacer:

```
df_2["ejemplo"] = df_2.apply(extraer_sublista, axis=1)
```

El resultado, en tu caso:

|  | values | n | expected | ejemplo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ['abc', 'cd2', 'axy'] | 2 | ['abc', 'cd2'] | ['abc', 'cd2'] |
| 1 | ['zxc', 'csa', 'vsa'] | 1 | ['zxc'] | ['zxc'] |
| 2 | ['was', 'sdf', 'kjd'] | 3 | ['was', 'sdf', 'kjd'] | ['was', 'sdf', 'kjd'] |

## Con lambda

La función `extraer_sublista()` que hemos necesitado escribir es tan breve que se puede escribir dentro de la propia llamada a `.apply()` mediante lo que se denomina una *expresión lambda*. En ese caso se omite el `return` porque una expresión lambda retorna automáticamente el resultado de evaluar la expresión que contiene.

Gracias a la lambda nos ahorramos tener que escribir la función `extraer_sublista()` y lo que es más importante aunque parezca trivial, nos ahorramos el tener que inventarnos un nombre para una función auxiliar que a fin de cuentas no vamos a necesitar más en ninguna otra parte del programa.

Quedaría así:

```
df_2["ejemplo"] = df_2.apply(lambda x: x["values"][:int(x.n)], axis=1)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Me funcionó a la perfección! y gracias por la explicación!